# module "QtQuick.Dialogs" version 1.3 is not installed

Tags: qt, qtquick2, qt-quick

I'm trying to import QtQuick.Dialogs version 1.3 in a code that runs without any issue with version 1.2. However on runtime I get the following error

> module "QtQuick.Dialogs" version 1.3 is not installed

I'm compiling with the default Desktop Qt 5.9.2 GCC 64bit kit

Anyone was a idea what is happening?

Comment: have you checked that QtQuick.Dialogs 1.3 is available with Qt 5.9.2 ... , it might be available with later Qt versions like 5.10. you need to check

Comment: if  importing  QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2 works, then 1.3 is not available in your qt version

Comment: According to the docs: https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qml-qtquick-dialogs-colordialog.html you have to use `import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2`

Comment: @eyllanesc I agree however they also have this page (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-filedialog.html) which is very confusing.

Comment: That is the documentation for the current version of Qt, that is, Qt 5.10, you should look in the documentation of your version of Qt. **doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9..** is different to **doc.qt.io**

Comment: @eyllanesc Oh man, ok. Still getting confused on Qt's site. Thanks

Comment: @eyllanesc, I've build with qt 5.10 it runs without any issue. However, the "defaultSuffix" property (the one I was after) doesn't seems to work. The fileUrl isn't appended of the defaultSuffix. any ideas?

Comment: @AlexandreBorowczyk Create a new question, place a [mcve] because I do not know if your code is correct.

Comment: @eyllanesc true,thanks : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253836/qts-filedialog-defaultsuffix-not-functionning

Answer (score 0):

Try to import without version: `import QtQuick.Dialogs`

In the Qt 5.15.2 it works.

If you use newest version then install actuality version for example `Qt 5.15`