# Qt's FileDialog defaultSuffix not functionning

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, filedialog, qt5.10

I'm using the following code to the new property of the filedialog under QtQuick.Dialogs 1.3 & Qt 5.10.0. I've build it using Qt Creator 5.10 default kit.

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")


FileDialog {
    id: fileDialog
    title: "Please choose a file"
    folder: shortcuts.home
    defaultSuffix: "txt"
    selectExisting: false
    selectMultiple: false
    onAccepted: {
        console.log("You chose: " + fileUrl)
        Qt.quit()
    }
    onRejected: {
        console.log("Canceled")
        Qt.quit()
    }
    Component.onCompleted: visible = true
}
}
```

My expectation are that if I choose a filename such as "MyFile", then the fileUrl would be "MyFile.txt". However it just returns "MyFile".

Comment: I tested this code, and it does return MyFile.txt .. strange you don't get that!

Comment: Same here, doenst work! Tested with Qt 5.10 and Qt 5.12. Qt Creator shows the error: "defaultSuffix" invalid property name. M16

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the code and it comes does come out with the ".txt". I am unsure of the problem but since there isn't really a question, you could append the default suffix using a [global property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257946/declare-global-property-in-qml-for-other-qml-files).

Comment: To double check you are entering a file name without the .txt and then the path comes back with the .txt appended? Also I'm notr sure I understand how I would use the global property